# Code inside Moq.Setup(...).Returns(...) only gets evaluated once

Tags: delegates, moq

I have a mocked Object which is passed to another Service.
the mock has a behavior subject that can be modified inside the Service or from my unit Tests. The test fails, because the mock is not returning the value I am expecting.
I already broke down the Problem to a small LinqPad snippet.

```
    void Main()
        {
            Moq.Mock<ITest> Mock = new Moq.Mock<ITest>();
            Mock.Setup(m => m.GetTestValue()).Returns(Task.FromResult(TestSubject.Value));
            TestSubject.Subscribe();
           //Setting TestSubject.Value to true
           TestSubject.OnNext(true);

           //But Mock still Returns false
           var testTask = Mock.Object.GetTestValue();
           testTask.Wait();
           testTask.Result.Dump();
        }

        public System.Reactive.Subjects.BehaviorSubject<bool> TestSubject = new System.Reactive.Subjects.BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);

        public interface ITest{
            Task<bool> GetTestValue();
        }
```

Edit: forgot to subscribe to the subject, but subscribing doesnt solve the Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the returns line to use a callback:

```
Mock.Setup(m => m.GetTestValue()).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(TestSubject.Value));
```

That's becase using it without a delegate will return the value it had when `.Setup` was called (`false`).

Comment: @abinmorth The `Returns` method on the type `IReturns<X, Y>` has two non-generic overloads (besides a bunch of generic overloads that are not relevant here). When you use `Returns(Y value)`, all Moq sees is one final value. Moq has no chance of re-evaluating whatever produced that value, since you do not give that information to Moq. But when you use the `Returns(Func<Y> valueFunction)` overload as suggested by this answer, Moq will call (invoke) that `valueFunction` delegate again each times it needs to mock that method again.